# Is there a way to have AutoCompleteTextView use the horizontal version?

Tags: android, autocomplete

Using an `AutoCompleteTextView`, it creates a drop down like list from the `EditText` field.  However, if you rotate the phone to landscape, it uses a horizontal scrolling list for the autocomplete.

Some devices that have autocomplete in their keyboard use this horizontal scrolling list.

Is there a way to have it use that view instead of the drop down in portrait mode?  If not, is that a View that can be customized?

Thanks